# Luck factors in odds of getting dwellers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

For fallout shelter, 
Will a dweller with not only charisma but with high luck have a higher chance of attracting other dwellers? (Radio)

Comment: Nobody should be asking what stats do anymore.  That question answers every stat exhaustively.  It also has links to the reddit posts with HUGE amount of data.  Please stop asking what stats do.

Answer (score -3):

No they wont, it is only scales from charisma. You can check the wiki for further information.

Comment: Telling people to check a wiki for further information is *dramatically* unhelpful.  At *least* include a link, if you have to mention a wiki.  Without that, your last sentence helping nothing at all.

Comment: He asked a really simple and small question, and i have answered.

Comment: Just because the question is simple, it doesn't mean you can't put a bit of effort into your answer. Ironicly, I feel that you wouldn't have attacted all these downvotes if you hadn't mentioned 'the wiki' *at all*. By mentionin it, but not linking it or even telling what it contains, people get the idea that you know more about the subject, but aren't telling us. Rather you expect us to search for the information ourselves. Or, that is the impression we are getting, at least.